# php POST Method Not Sending File Field Data

Tags: php, post, input-type-file

I'm trying to send a pfd file from an html forms

It's being called from UploadNewNewsletter.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="./queries/upload_newsletter.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Newsletter: <input type="file" name="news"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

And being received in upload_newsletter.php

```
<?php
$target_path = "../PDFNewsletters/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['news']['name']);

echo '$target_path';
?>
```

When I submit a file under about 7.5mb it echoes `../PDFNewsletters/<filename.pdf>`
but anything over that echoes just `../PDFNewsletters/`

And finally, the post request looks like

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypc53TBYKknpKG8A6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="news"; filename="Homework20.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarypc53TBYKknpKG8A6--
```

I set post_max_size = 40M
although when i set post_max_size = 0M it still sends in a text field's data if I were to add it to the html file, so i'm not positive I'm even in the correct php.ini.default file.

Why would it send in the filename and not the data?

**UPDATE**
It does work for .jpg files which makes me think I have the wrong php.ini.default file

Comment: Did you also set `upload_max_filesize`? It defaults to 2M

Comment: @Cfreak It is also set to upload_max_filesize = 40M

Comment: add phpinfo(); temporarily to the top of your file and at the top of the info it spits out it will tell you the path to the php.ini file that is being used, and also further down the current upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings

Comment: @glendav The upload_max_filesize and post_max_size were showing different values on the phpInfo page and the php.ini.default.

I just solved the problem though.
I needed to duplicate the php.ini.default file and rename the duplicate to php.ini. Then in php.ini I modified it to the desired settings. Then, to get the changes to take, I needed to restart the apache server.

Thanks for your help.